# Training job runtime exceeded MaxRuntimeInSeconds provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to run my model 30 days in using aws sagemaker training job, but its max time is 5 days, how to resume the earlier to proceed further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open a support ticket to increase `Longest run time for a training job`
   to 2419200 seconds (28 days). (this can't be adjusted using the service quotas in AWS Web console).
2. Using the SageMaker Python SDK, when creating an [Estimator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.Estimator), set `max_run=2419200`.
3. Implement [Resume from checkpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html) in your training script.

Also, the questions in @rok's answer are very relevant to consider.

Answer (score 1):

<s>According to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_StoppingCondition.html) the maximum allowed runtime is 28 days, not 5. Check your configuration please</s> . You are right, according to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html) the maximum runtime for a training job is 5 days. There are multiple things you can do: more powerful (multiple) GPU to reduce training time, or save checkpoint and restart training from there. Anyway 30 days looks like a very big training time (with associated cost), are you sure you need that ?

Actually you could ask for service quotas increase from [here](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/sagemaker/quotas) but as you can see `Longest run time for a training job` is not adjustable. So I don't you have any other choice of either using checkpoints or greater GPUs.

Comment: ResourceLimitExceeded: An error occurred (ResourceLimitExceeded) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: The request delta of 2419200 Seconds for 'Longest run time for a training job' is greater than the account-level service-limit of 432000 Seconds. Please contact AWS support to request an increase for this limit.

Comment: I just realized you were right, sorry. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have access to a basic GPU and I can not change the algorithm to not use GPU. So what I did,

1. I used SageMaker Studio Notebook. I first tested the code with a smaller dataset, doubled checked the checkpointing works or not.
2. Placed the actual code in the Notebook and "Run All Cells"
3. Closed the browser and waited for few days. The model training was successful(more than 5 days I think)

Interestingly, the next time when I opened the Notebook even it says the Kernel is dead, you can still open the terminal and check the progress. So as long as you don't kill the instance the process runs in the backend even if the browser tab is closed.

But I am thinking of moving long running jobs on EC2 Instances(if possible using managed spot training - I have'nt been successful yet in getting a GPU on Spot)